# Output from WMI queries not coming out correctly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am querying the WMI class `Win32_ShadowCopy` for disk information to check for multiple things. Status code, Last Snapshot, etc. I can run this script on the local machine and it returns the correct information. Once I use `Import-Csv` that contains the servers and disk to check shadowcopy health it returns the wrong output.

Example Input 1:

```
Server  Drive
inms145     C
inms145     D
inms145     E
mission-1   C
mission-1   Q
mission-1   V
mission-1   W
mission-1   T
mission-1   X
mission-1   U
mission-1   Z
```

Example output (wrong):

```
ServerName Last_Snapshot                             Volume                                 Condition        SCDrive   LsDrives                  Status
INMS145 20160621135802.865078-240   \\?\Volume{022366e6-d8a5-49fc-8c82-263032d6c6a3}\   OK - Status Code: 12    E   C D E C Q V W T X U Z   Enabled Correctly on E
INMS145 20160621135802.865078-240   \\?\Volume{022366e6-d8a5-49fc-8c82-263032d6c6a3}\   OK - Status Code: 12    E   C D E C Q V W T X U Z   Enabled Correctly on E
```

Example Input 2:

```
Server  Drive
inms145     C
inms145     D
inms145     E
```

Example output (correct):

```
ServerName Last_Snapshot                              Volume                               Condition        SCDrive    LsDrives        Status
INMS145 20160621135802.865078-240   \\?\Volume{022366e6-d8a5-49fc-8c82-263032d6c6a3}\   OK - Status Code: 12     E       C D E     Enabled Correctly on E
INMS145        N/A                                       N/A                               NOT ENABLED        C D E      C D E     Not Enabled on C D E
```

Script:

```
$CSVPath  = "\\SERVER\E$\Utilities\Scripts\Set_DashboardData\ShadowCopy\Servers_Drives.csv"
$rPath    = "\\SERVER\E$\Utilities\Scripts\Set_DashboardData\ShadowCopy\Results.csv"
$Pshell2F = "\\SERVER\E$\Utilities\Scripts\Set_DashboardData\ShadowCopy\export-csv-pshell.2.ps1"
$SCHash   = @()
$SCArray  = @()

if ((Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ProductName).ProductName -like "*Windows Server 2008*") {
    $Pshell2F | Out-Null
    $SC_Get = Import-Csv $CSVPath | ForEach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $_.server -Class Win32_ShadowCopy | foreach {
          $_ | Select-Object Volumename,@{n="SCDrive";e={$vol08=$_.volumename;(gwmi -Class Win32_Volume | select deviceid | ? {$_.deviceid -eq $vol08}).DeviceID}}
        }
    }
} elseif ((Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ProductName).ProductName -like "*Windows Server 2012*") {
    $SC_Get = Import-Csv $CSVPath | ForEach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $_.server -Class Win32_ShadowCopy | foreach {
            $_ | Select-Object  PSComputerName,InstallDate,Volumename,State,@{n="SCDrive";e={$vol12=$_.volumename;(Get-Volume | ? {$_.path -eq $vol12}).DriveLetter}},@{n="LsDrives";e={Import-Csv $CSVPath | select -ExpandProperty drive}}
        }
    }
}

$SC_Get | foreach {
    $props = @{
        ServerName      = $_.PSComputerName
        Last_Snapshot   = $_.InstallDate
        Volume          = $_.Volumename
        Condition       = $_.State
        SCDrive         = $_.SCDrive
        LsDrives        = $_.LsDrives
        Status          = $_.State
    }
    New-Object PsObject -Property $props
} | ForEach-Object {
    $SCHash = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        'ServerName'    = $_.ServerName
        'Last_Snapshot' = $_.Last_Snapshot
        'Volume'        = $_.Volume
        'Condition'     = $_.Condition
        'SCDrive'       = $_.SCDrive
        'LsDrives'      = $_.LsDrives
        'Status'        = $_.Status
    }
    #The altered data is put into the empty array created earlier and the select statement specifies the order to put it in. 
    $SCArray += $SCHash | Select-Object ServerName,Last_Snapshot,Volume,Condition,SCDrive,LsDrives,Status
}

$SC = $SCArray

$SCFilt = $SCArray | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LsDrives | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $($SC | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SCDrive)} | select -Unique

$SCArray | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.LsDrives -match $_.SCDrive -and $_.Last_Snapshot -like "") {
        $_.Status = "Enabled - No Snaps"
        $_.Condition = "NO SNAPSHOTS - Status Code: " + ($($_.Condition))
    }

    if ($_.LsDrives -match $_.SCDrive -and $_.Last_Snapshot -like "**" -and $_.Status -ne "12") {
        $_.Status = "Enabled-Snaps-State doesnt equal 12"
        $_.Condition = "NOT OK - Status Code: " + ($($_.Condition))
    }

    if ($_.LsDrives -match $_.SCDrive -and $_.Last_Snapshot -like "**" -and $_.Status -eq "12") {
        $_.Status = "Enabled Correctly on " + ($($_.SCDrive))
        $_.Condition = "OK - Status Code: " + ($($_.Condition))
    }
}

$SCArray | select -Unique | Export-Csv $rPath -NoTypeInformation -Force | Out-Null

$SCArray | ForEach-Object {
    if ($SCFilt) {
        $_.Status = "Not Enabled on " + ($($SCfilt))
        $_.Condition = "NOT ENABLED"
        $_.SCDrive = "$($SCFilt)"
        $_.Last_Snapshot = 'N/A'
        $_.Volume = 'N/A'
    }
}

$SCArray | select -Unique | Export-Csv $rPath -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append | Out-Null
```

How do I get the output to correlate with the next server in the list? It is also combining the column of drives and not running the information from the other server. If I run `$SCArray | select -Unique`, it will only return the inms145 even though mission-01 is in that list.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why do you run a WMI query against remote servers, then select properties depending on the local operating system version and add local volume information? Why do you query each server multiple times? Do you want to obtain information from the local machine or from a remote host? How are local volumes related to remote shadow copies? Your code is so convoluted that it's borderline incomprehensible.

Comment: I am running WMI queries to look at the win32_shadowcopy class and I have to use win32_logicaldisk to get volume information. Get-Volume is not a valid cmdlet in 2008. I query them multiple times because I could not figure how to do (inms145 | C,D,E,F) and treat each letter as an object to correspond to the detected shadowcopy drives. The user would input the drives that are supposed to have shadow copy enabled. If the drives did not match up with what the shadowcopy class provided it would pop out the errors in the if statements.

Comment: Also, I did find one script that queries shadowcopy information a lot more effectively. 

[link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Remote-Shadow-Volume-e5a72619)

Comment: Again, why are you mixing local and remote queries? And why do you make a remote query depend on the local operating system version? That's probably the main source of your problems.